# What is negative point on using W3C presentational xhtml tag?

Tags: xhtml, w3c

If some xhtml tag are presentational but valid in W3C then if i use then what is negative point of using those Tags in terms of semantic, code maintanance. I'm talking about **b**, **big**, **br**, **hr**, **i**, and **small**.Are all presentational tags deprecated?

Comment: More or less answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577987/what-are-the-merits-of-using-tt-i-b-big-and-small-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: There is no real negative point to using those tags.

To answer more fully: The presentation elements you listed are all indeed valid in XHTML and NOT depreciated: **big**, **i**, **small**, **sub**, **tt** and **hr**.

The only downside to using them is your own site's maintainability: It is easier to maintain/change a website when all the presentational elements are stored away from formatting in CSS.

So, apart from the possibility of more work for you (and anyone else who works on the website), there aren't any real negative points.

Please note: **br** is NOT presentational, it is considered formatting, like **p** and **h1**.

Comment: You mean **br** is semantic, like **p** and **h1**. And so it is. It means a semantic line break such as the end of a line of poetry. It's hard to think of valid uses outside of poetry though.

Comment: @Django Reinhardt- as you wrote "The only downside to using them is your own site's maintainability: It is easier to maintain/change a website when all the presentational elements are stored away from formatting in CSS." but we can wrote css for presentational tags in css.

Comment: @jitendra Sorry I don't understand what you've written. You can't put any of the tags you've listed in CSS files. You can put {font-style:italic} in CSS, but you can't put `<i>` in it, for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Phrase elements](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_phrase_elements.asp) like <strong> and <em> are more semantically correct and are able to achieve richer effect through CSS (rather than simply bold or italic).

These elements also takes standard attributes and event attributes.

<strike>And yes, elements: b, big, br, hr, i, and small are deprecating and not supported in HTML5.</strike>

**Edit:** Thanks @Alohci for correction.

Comment: Actually b, br, hr, i and small are all conforming (i.e. valid) in HTML5. Of that list only "big" is obsolete. The full list of obsolete elements in HTML5 is available at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features